# Converting a string input from user to a numeric (int) value.

Tags: java, string, int

I've been trying different methods for converting a user string input into an int I could compare and build an "if-then" statement. Every time I tried testing it, it just threw exception. Can anyone look at my Java code and help me find the way? I'm clueless about it (also a noob in programming). If I'm breaking any rules please let me know I'm new here. Thank you.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
 System.out.println("Sorry couldn't find your user profile " + userName + ".");
 System.out.println("Would you like to create a new user profile now? (Enter Y for yes), (Enter N for no and exit).");
 try {
     BufferedReader answer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String addNewUser = answer.readLine();
     Character i = new Character(addNewUser.charAt(0));
     String s = i.toString();
     int answerInDecimal = Integer.parseInt(s);
     System.out.println(answerInDecimal);
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
     System.out.println("You've mistyped the answer.");
 e.getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: What is your input? What is the Exception stack trace?

Comment: Please post the stack trace--

Comment: Just a side suggestion, you can use `String s = addNewUser.substring(0,1)` to get the first character as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to convert the string (which should be a single character, Y or N) into its character value, and then retrieve the numerical representation of the character.

If you want to turn Y or N into their decimal representation, you have to perform a cast to int:

```
BufferedReader answer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String addNewUser = answer.readLine();
char i = addNewUser.charAt(0);
int integerChar = (int) i;       //The important part
System.out.println(integerChar);
```

This will return the integer representation of the character that the user input. It may also be useful to call the String.toUpperCase() method in order to ensure that different inputs of Y/N or y/n do not give different values.

However, you could also do an if-else based upon the character itself, rather than converting it to an integer.

```
BufferedReader answer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String addNewUser = answer.readLine();
char i = addNewUser.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
if (i == 'Y') {
    //Handle yes
} else if (i == 'N') {
    //Handle no
} else {
    System.out.println("You've mistyped the answer.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to ask them to **Enter 0 for yes and 1 for No** ? Maybe?

You're asking the user to type Y or N and then you're trying to parse that to an integer. That will always throw an exception.

**EDIT** -- As others have pointed out, if you want to continue to use Y or N, you should do something along the lines of

```
String addNewUser = answer.readLine();
if ( addNewUser.toLowerCase().startsWith("y") ) {
// Create new profile
}
```

Comment: Well, I was trying to make it intuitive for the user and also I'm taking the hard way on purpose to learn how to deal with this kind of situation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (addNewUser.startsWith("Y") || addNewUser.startsWith("y")) {` instead.
Or (as Mark pointed) `if (addNewUser.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {`.
 BTW maybe look at [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/)?

Comment: `if (addNewUser.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {` is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I find this answer to work perfectly! I would now investigate ".toLowerCase().startsWith" since I didn't knew about them yet.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt is just for converting text numbers into integers: everything else gets a NumberFormatException.

If you want the decimal ASCII value of a character, just cast it to an int.

Comment: Thank you I now know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `String` to `int`, unless you know the `String` contains a valid integer.

**Firstly**, using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for input is better, since its faster
   and you don't need to get into the hassle of using streams, if you're
   a beginner. This is how `Scanner` will be used to take input:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // this is where the Scanner class resides
```

...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // "System.in" is the stream, you could also pass a String, or a File object to take input from
System.out.println("Would you like to ... Enter 'Y' or 'N':");
String input = sc.next();
input = input.toUpperCase();
char choice = sc.charAt(0);
if(choice == 'Y') 
{ } // do something

else if(choice == 'N')
{ } // do something

else
System.err.println("Wrong choice!");
```

This code could also be shortened to one line (however you won't be
   able to check a third "wrong choice" condition):

```
if ( new Scanner(System.in).next().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y')
      { } // do something
   else  // for 'N'
      { } // do something
```

**Secondly**, `char` to `int` conversion just requires an explicit type
   cast:

```
   char ch = 'A';
   int i = (int)ch;  // explicit type casting, 'i' is now 65 (ascii code of 'A')
```

**Thirdly**, even if you take input from a buffered input stream, you
   will take input in a `String`. So extracting the first character from
   the string and checking it, simply requires a call to the `charAt()`
   function with **0** as a parameter. It returns a character, which can
   then be compared to a single character in single quotes like this:

```
   String s = in.readLine();
   if(s.charAt(0) == 'Y') { } // do something
```

**Fourthly**, its a very bad idea to put the whole program in a `try`
   block and `catch` `Exception` at the end. An `IOException` can be
   thrown by the `readline()` function, and `parseInt()` could throw a
   `NumberFormatException`, so you won't be able to handle the 2
   exceptions separately. In this question, the code is small enough for
   this to be ignored, but in practice, there will be many functions
   that can throw exceptions, hence it becomes easy to lose track of exactly which function threw what exception and proper exception handling becomes quite difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm a beginner and have learned from your answer. I appreciate the help!